# Do I need to go through all the hassle to allow users to view my google calendar?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I want to expose my google calendar in my web app, and through one of my forms, I'd like to create an event/appointment in my calendar. Do I need to go through all the OAuth2 stuff to achieve this? I find the documentation extremely ambigous, and asking users to log into google for such a simple use case seems unnecessary. Am I missing something very obvious? 
Could you please point me in the right direction?

Isn't there like a simple HTTP API that I could authenticate my app as a Google Calendar user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see, you're only needing to authenticate *your web app* with *your* Google Calendar. So, there's no need for your users to log in to Google or anything like that.

Yes, you'll still need to use OAuth2 to allow your web app to update your Google Calendar. After you initially grant your web app access to your calendar data, you'll get the access token and a refresh token. The refresh token can be used to automatically generate a new access token, meaning your web app will continue to be authenticated without needing you or your users to do anything.

Comment: How much time will a refresh token last?

Comment: I believe they last forever - that is, they don't have an in-built expiry date. They're valid until you revoke access to your web app.